# Read OS(Linux and MAC) environment variable to not expose backend IP's and Credentials in angular 9

Tags: security, build, environment-variables, angular9, system-variable

I'm trying to build and deploy my angular 9 project in production environment. The main goal is to protect my back-end services IP address and credentials as these environments can't be exposed to anyone for security issue. Build and Serve works fine for current setups but the problem is i can't access/read environment variables except one that i created using shell. Only i can read the value of **TEST1** variable but **BASE_URL** and **NOTIFICATION_URL** shows undefined. One important thing is that i have no idea about system OS environment variable and don't system environment will work in production build. I just googled and created those variables in shell and echo shows value properly but i'm not sure i'm in a proper way. Please Suggest me the suitable way or currently where i made mistake. And what about production?

**Shell variables i created:**

[image: shell variables]

**Custom Webpack**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
            NOTIFICATION_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.NOTIFICATION_URL),
            TEST1: JSON.stringify(process.env.TEST1)
        }
    })]
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore
declare var process: Process;

interface Process {
    env: Env
}

interface Env {
    BASE_URL: string
    NOTIFICATION_URL: string
    TEST1: string
}

interface GlobalEnvironment{
    process: Process;
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    baseUrl: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
    notificationUrl: `${process.env.NOTIFICATION_URL}`,
    test: `${process.env.TEST1}`,
};
```

Comment: every service provides you as a local variable environment to create/delete variables instead of creating in the terminal. if you're using Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars, or you just can create .env file using ssh!

Answer (score 0):

TO SET environment variables permanently on server

edit `/etc/environment`

Paste:

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/
TEST_URL=http://localhost:8080/
```

Save

To Apply on current run: `source /etc/environment`

Note: When you ssh into the machine and use export TEST=test, Then a session wide environment variable would be created, Only the commands in that session can access it. And it would get deleted after closing the ssh session.